# Best methods to group multiple actions together (as one event)

Tags: ajax, action, grouping

At work we use a web application (attask.com) to record projects and tasks etc. It has lots of nice features like comments and status update (ill stop before you think im selling it!)

anywho, On the site you can update the status of a project and this is saved via ajax. Then shortly after I could comment on the project. In the update section of this project these two actions will appear together as if they were performed as one...

If you were to perform  the same sort of functionality, how would you go about it?

One method I have thought of is to have a hidden box and store a GUID in this when the page loads. Unquie to the page load. Then any ajax calls would use this GUID when posting data back and therefore things could be grouped this way.

But I would like to hear other peoples idea or how they have gone about it if they have had to do something similiar

Comment: Maybe you could clarify when would two actions like that not appear as if they were performed as one? Different user? After some time? After page refresh? After loosing some kind of session?

Comment: What type of actions change the behavior and cause the status update and comment to appear as two different updates? For instance, updating the status, browsing off the project then back on, then commenting - does that make it appear as two updates?

Comment: I will look into it and see what causes it two become two updates

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no concept of user identity through a sign in system, a guid passed to a javascript variable on the rendered page would provide a simple solution. There would be no need to hide something like that inside a container.

When an action is performed, the guid would be sent with the AJAX request. Upon receipt of an action, the server could check if a previous action carried out by a user with the same guid occurred within x many seconds. If this is the case, the actions would be considered a pair and the 'feed' model would be updated accordingly.

My only experience of building something similar was a event planner that did not require user sign up to select days on a calendar. The selection of days was carried out by AJAX, so it was necessary to determine which calendar in the database to update based on a guid that was passed to the page on load.

It's also worth noting that you don't really need a 'guid', any unique string will do.

Comment: why would it matter if their was a sign in for the user? just because you know who the user is, doesn't mean you can insure the actions are one. Or am i missing something?